# What's the maximum number of symbols that can be exported from a shared library?

Tags: c++, c, dll, shared-libraries, dllexport

A project I'm on just ran up against the maximum number of symbols that could be exported from a dll.  That got me wondering what this limit is on other platforms.  It's not easy to google, so I'm asking here.

Windows?
Linux?
MacOS?
BSD?

Anything more exotic if you know it?

Comment: There isn’t a hard limit.

Comment: So what exactly was the error message and on which platform/compiler/IDE/...?

Comment: How many symbols were you exporting?  We’re they C++ mangled names that are a mile long?

Comment: It could be a toolchain limitation or an OS limitation.

Comment: Linux and MacOS, and I think BSD, too, all use ELF format for shared libraries.  In this format there is a string table, and symbol definitions contain a 64-bit index into that table.  That format therefore has a hard limit of 2^64 exported symbols, though in practice, you don't have enough storage for a shared library with the many symbols.

Comment: Windows uses 16-bit integers for ordinals, so 65535 is the limit